# Symfony Serializer doesn't convert an array of objects from camelCase to snake_case

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization

Can someone help me with this?
I'm trying to serialize an object to json using the Symfony Serializer, it does convert object to json but it doesnt convert an array of objects from camelCase to snake_case.

Im currently using the default Serializer with Symfony 3.3

Below is my code.

## app/config/config.yml

```
 framework: 
  serializer:  
    enabled: true
    name_converter: 'serializer.name_converter.camel_case_to_snake_case'
```

## app/config/services.yml

```
 services:
    get_set_method_normalizer:
        class:Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer
        public: true
        tags: [serializer.normalizer]
```

Persons.php

```
class Person{
     private $firstName;
     private $lastName;
     private $email;

     //setters and getters
}
```

PersonController.php

```
class PersonController extends Controller {
     /**
      * @Route("api/person")
      * @Method("POST")
      */
     public function person(){
         $person = new Person();
          $person->setFirstName("test");
          $person->setLastName("test");
          $person->setEmail("test@test.com");

         $person1 = new Person();
         $person1->setFirstName("test 1");
          $person1->setLastName("test 1");
          $person1->setEmail("test1@test.com");
         $arr = array($person, $person1);
         $serializer = $this->get("serializer");
         return new Response($serializer->serialize($arr,"json"));
     }

}
```

Below is the current output.

```
[
  {
     "firstName":"test",
     "lastName":"test"
     "email":"test@test.com"
  },
  {
     "firstName":"test 1",
     "lastName":"test 1"
     "email":"test@test.com"
  }
]
```

Expected output would be:

```
 [
   {
      "first_name":"test",
      "last_name":"test",
      "email":"test@test.com"
   },
   {
      "first_name":"test 1",
      "last_name":"test 1",
      "email":"test1@test.com"
   }
]
```

Comment: Using your code above, I get the expected output on my machine. You're sure you cleared the cache? Can you post the use Statements?

Comment: I have the same problem on Symfony 4. I gave up and switch to Jms Serializer.

Answer (score 4):

For symfony 4 this worked for me:

```
Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer:
    public: true
    arguments: ['@serializer.mapping.class_metadata_factory', '@serializer.name_converter.camel_case_to_snake_case']
    tags: [serializer.normalizer]
```

Put that code inside your app/config/services.yaml, inside the "services" section.

Answer (score 2):

try explicitly pass arguments for your service:

```
get_set_method_normalizer:
        class:Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer
        public: true
        arguments: ['@serializer.mapping.class_metadata_factory', '@serializer.name_converter.camel_case_to_snake_case']
        tags: [serializer.normalizer]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to add an alias for `camel_case_to_snake_case`

```
services:
    ...
    Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\NameConverterInterface: '@serializer.name_converter.camel_case_to_snake_case'
```